# What would happen if my internet connection is lost while I am upgrading from 12.04LTS to 14.04LTS?

Tags: upgrade, internet

I want to upgrade my OS from 12.04 to 14.04. I found how to get it. But I've one more question:

What would happen if I gave the command to upgrade, it starts but after downloading some or many file my internet connection is lost? Will I still be able to use 12.04?
And what about downloaded files of 14.04. Would they still be on pc or will I have to download them from the beginning?

Actually my problem is **not** *system instability* if internet connection is lost but the amount of data remained to be download. Will I have to download the whole package from the beginning? As I was a windows user, I saw that this is not the case with windows. It keeps downloading files and when downloading is complete it asks the user to install them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I know the update process is as folows:

1. The update manager downloads **all the files**
2. The update manager applies all the changes and installs all the files

In other words, if your connection is interrupted, nothing will change to your system because the first step is not finished. Step two is executed *if and only if step 1 was successful*.

This is the upgrade manager you'll see. Note how first the new channels are fetched, then the new pacakges, only then to proceed to install them.

[image: upgrade manager photo]

Just before the actual fetching of the packages starts, you will get the following dialogue box which confirms my answer:

[image: upgrade dialogue box 13.10->14.04]

Note: You should not be worried so much about your connection, but about making sure your power source stays alive. If you switch off your computer or your power source whilst the update is ongoing, then your system will be messed up.

Also as a general note: always keep two external backups of all your files before you upgrade *and* do not upgrade a production system without having a large amount of time and knowledge about what to do if something in the upgrade did not go as expected.

For the rest, welcome to 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

About the downloaded files, they will be saved when the connection lost. You can redo the upgrade and this time it will resume the downloading. You will not have to download whole data again.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know.