# Internet connection went down while upgrading version

Tags: wireless, upgrade, internet, do-release-upgrade

While running

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

my internet connection went down. The last messages printed were these

```
Restoring original system sate

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
```

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449524/what-would-happen-if-my-internet-connection-is-lost-while-i-am-upgrading-from-12) might be related, but what I want to know is: **how do I continue the upgrade process?**

Comment: There are two main stages to `do-release-upgrade`, first is the download where if connection goes down, nothing was changed anyway.  The second stage is the installation of the new packages (which mostly doesn't use internet, though some packages [flash as I recall was one] do use web, but they are unimportant so release-upgrade should have completed with only cosmetic issues (missing flash is a good thing anyway). It sounds like the first download step aborted, and nothing was done - so re-do it will do what you want.

Comment: @guiverc That's what I thought. Will do it now. Hope internet does not go down this time.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main stages to do-release-upgrade,

1. download packages
2. install packages

If during the download a connection goes down, it'll abort and restore your system back to what it was (ie. put back you '*dingo*' sources instead of the changed '*eoan*' sources) and it's this that was 'restored' I'm betting in your posted message.

The second stage is the installation of the new packages (which mostly doesn't use internet, though some packages [flash as I recall was one] do use web, but they are unimportant so release-upgrade should have completed with only cosmetic issues (missing flash is a good thing anyway).

It sounds like the first download step aborted, and nothing was done - so re-do it will do what you want.